# Perform action once a form has been validated

Tags: 7, forms, hooks

On Drupal 7, I would like to execute some code once a form has been validated.

I have seen many usage of [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) : implementing this hook and adding a custom callback to `$form['#validate']` I could perform action *on validation*.

But I need to be absolutely sure the form ***has been validated*** to perform my actions.

Is there some other hook to do so ? Or something I could do in `hook_form_alter` to ensure that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a submit callback instead of a validation callback. Submit callbacks are called after the form has been validated.

```
function yourmodule_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'yourmodule_custom_submit_callback';
}

function yourmodule_custom_submit_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // Execute here your code
}
```

Comment: Oh! I thought sumbit callbacks were called when the user submit the form. Are you sure about that ? On https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#submit_property it says "A list of custom submit functions that will be called when the element is submitted. This is usually to add additional submit functions to a form, or to use an alternate function rather than the default form submission function which is the form ID with _submit appended to it."

Comment: Submit handlers are called after the validation handlers. Otherwise it would have no meaning to validate the form after it is already submitted.